# How can I write readable subroutine hash arguments?

Tags: perl

At work we like to pass arguments into subroutines as a hash ref:

```
my $manager = DatabaseManager->new({
    'sHost'     => 'my_host',
    'sDatabase' => 'some_database'
});
```

The object itself has an init function that looks like this:

```
sub _init
{
    my ($self, $phArgs) = @_;

    $self->{_sHost}     = $phArgs->{sHost};
    $self->{_sDatabase} = $phArgs->{sDatabase};
}
```

Is there any way to tidy this up? Even if just the first line could be clearer I think it'd be an improvement. Something like

```
sub _init
{
    my ($self, ($host, $database) ) = @_;

    $self->{_sHost}     = $host;
    $self->{_sDatabase} = $database;
}
```

Then it's clear what the subroutine needs. Any ideas?

Comment: "At work we like to pass arguments into subroutines as a hash ref:" That never made sense to me.

Comment: @ikegami - it makes perfect sense when you may want to pass things OTHER than the hash ref. API design isn't always black and white

Comment: @DVK, Take your own advice. You're saying it isn't always black and white, but you didn't consider the circumstances: 1) There is nothing else being passed, and 2) he said it's company policy. Don't pretend I said one should never passes references to subs.

Comment: @DVK, Even if there were positional parameters passed too, you can just as easily do `$x,$y,f=>1,g=>2` as you can do `$x,$y,{f=>1,g=>2}`. There are three differences to passing a hash ref: 1) It's harder to read because of extraneous, functionless characters. 2) It forces extra typing throughout the code, both on the caller side and the called side of the sub call. 3) It creates a needless variable. So yeah, generally speaking, it's a bad practice.

Comment: @ikegami - Now, try to imagine if "y" is ALSO a hash content-wise. Now, you will turn into Steve Yegge and rant how Perl sucks because it flattens out lists. Or be force to agree that sometimes, passing a hashref is a GOOD design choice in API. Please note, I didn't say that passing a hashref is ALWAYS the best choice- for reasons you listed, it may not be. But sometimes, it IS the best choice, which is what I said in the first comment. It's not black and white.

Comment: Re "Now, try to imagine if `y` is ALSO a hash content-wise", huh? `y` is not the subroutine's arguments. Stop pretending I said it's bad to pass references to a subroutine. It's a straw man. I never said that. I already told you I never said that. You're just trolling at this point.

Comment: @ikegami: so what specifically is it that never made sense to you?

Comment: @innaM, The OP's practice of passing arguments using a hash ref. `f({...})`

Comment: This little conversation doesn't make any kind of sense to me. Can't someone get over-excited about the Hungarian notation crap instead? What is `ph` supposed to tell me?

Comment: @innaM, Re hungarian notation, see [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). It's a great tool; it's just not used right here. (e.g. I use $foo_fh vs $foo_fn vs $foo_qfn all the time.)

Comment: Exactly. And exactly not what is going on here. But maybe I'm just getting hung up on the notation when what really irks me is the corporate bureaucracy that is going on here. And the mandatory `_init` method.

Comment: There are some existing styling constraints but I also have some freedom. I was really just looking for something more readable, like what I'm used to from php: `function initialize($host, $database) {...}`. This makes it clear that the function requires a host and a db in its constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you want to "name" the options. You could do something like:

```
my ($self, $phArgs) = @_;
my ($sHost, $sDatabase) = @{$phArgs}{qw( sHost sDatabase )};
```

But then you end up mentioning `sHost` and `sDatabase` four times because you follow up with

```
$self->{_sHost}     = $sHost;
$self->{_sDatabase} = $sDatabase;
```

There's nothing you can do about that, since that's specifically what you want. I think this is crazy considering the entire sub could be written as:

```
my ($self, $phArgs) = @_;
@$self{qw( _sHost sDatabase )} = @$phArgs{qw( sHost sDatabase )};
```

or

```
my ($self, $phArgs) = @_;
$self->{"_".$_} = $phArgs->{$_} for qw( sHost sDatabase );
```

Comment: Next time... just use comment flags. Some people just aren't worth contending with - I'm sure you didn't want to waste your time either.